# Angular date picker showing wrong year in IE(instead of 2019 its showing 1919)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, datepicker

I dont know why IE is showing wrong date(year) from angular date picker. In chrome it works fine but not in IE. 
If I get date 1/1/2019 it shows 1/1/1919, similarly for 1/1/2016-->1/1/1916. Basically it shows 100 years back. In chrome everything is fine(It shows 1/1/2019-->1/1/2019)

here is the value is set

```
 if (releaseEntryTypeId === 1) {
                this.releaseModificationItem.releaseManagementInteractiveForm
                .get('startDate')
                .setValue(moment.utc(this.releaseDetails.startDate).toISOString());
              }
```

formBiuilder

```
 this.releaseManagementInteractiveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      releaseEntryType: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      ..............................................
      startDate: new FormControl(moment())
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="schedule-release-date" *ngIf="formControls['releaseEntryType'].value === 1">
      <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="">
        <input required matInput [matDatepicker]="releaseDatePicker" placeholder="Release Date" [formControl]="formControls['startDate']">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="releaseDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #releaseDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

I found similar issue by someone on stackoverflow:- [How do I fix a year of two digits in mat-datepicker in IE browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025706/how-do-i-fix-a-year-of-two-digits-in-mat-datepicker-in-ie-browser)

As per solution, I tried to implement moment but it didn't work for me too

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybdbdr?file=polyfills.ts) to make angular datepicker work in IE 11.

You could download the project, cd into the project and run `npm install` to install the project. I also modified the **datepicker-moment-example.ts** file like this in local:

```
...
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
//import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';

const moment = _moment;
...
```

The demo is mostly the same with the answer in the similar issue you found. You need to run `npm i moment` to install the package and implement [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).